Does research account for improved efficiency due to novelty when comparing language-learning methods?
The papers I look at in language-learning research often take a group of students and tweak their class in one way (like as explained here).  Perhaps half will continue as usual (a control), and the other half will use a new method (an intervention).  The researchers often conclude the new methods led the students to learn more words.   However, in my experience, new methods (even if they are objectively worse methods) tend to be temporarily more effective than old methods, and I think this could lead to research bias.
To illustrate the concept, suppose we have a language that has 7 words (A, B, C, D, E, F, G); suppose Method 1 teaches 5 of these words (A, B, C, D, E), and Method 2 teaches 4 of these words (D, E, F, G).  Objectively, Method 1 is better than Method 2.  If the school regularly uses Method 1 for teaching when the researchers then come in and conduct their experiment, they'll find Method 1 isn't especially helpful because the students have already learned A, B, C, D, E.  They'll conclude that Method 2 outperforms Method 1 because the students quickly learn the words F, G.  (And had the school regularly taught using Method 2, the researchers would instead conclude that Method 1 is better, the direct opposite conclusion.)
This has been my experience in language learning, too.  If I use a new study method, even if it's far less efficient than what I'm currently using, it'll quickly fill in some "gaps" in my knowledge, and give an illusion of efficiency.
Hence...
Questions: Does research account for improved efficiency due to novelty when comparing language-learning methods?
